# Tinting vector drawable with a selector

Tags: android, android-theme, android-icons

Currently I am using a material theme and minsdk 23 and target api 28. I have a vector icon that uses a selector like this:

```
    android:width="22dp"
    android:height="22dp"
    android:viewportWidth="22"
    android:viewportHeight="22">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/my_selector"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M9,2H8.5858L8.2929,2.2929L4.2929,6.2929L4,6.5858V7V19V20H5H17H18V19V3V2H17H9ZM10,4H16V18H6V8H9H10V7V4Z" />
</vector>
```

and the `color/my_selector.xml` is set up to response to me enabling and disabling this item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/gray_100" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/gray_400" />
</selector>
```

This works well but I need to start using theme color attributes instead of referencing colors directly in the `color/my_selector.xml`. My selector is changing to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" />
</selector>
```

This does not work (the resulting color being set is magenta which is not what I want). I believe I need to use tinting but can't figure out how to do it all in xml (not programatically).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any success with this issue? I am fighting with the same problem now...